# Add Back Next toggles to simple slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, toggleswitch

I found some simple code that I am using to make a slideshow but it is an auto play slideshow and I'd like to have the auto play function as well as next/back toggles.

Here is my code:

```
$(function () {

    $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

    setInterval(function () {
        $('#slideshow > div:first')
            .fadeOut(2000)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .end()
            .appendTo('#slideshow');
    }, 6000);

});
```

and HTML

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div>
        <a href="agency/thestudio.html">
            <img src="Images/slide1.gif" border="0" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="agency/mm.html">
            <img src="Images/slide2.gif" border="0" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="agency/thestudio.html">
            <img src="Images/slide3.gif" border="0" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are happening? Provide more information please...

Comment: it is a simple slideshow  using some java script and html. the slide show cycles through the different divs automatically. i am trying to add next/ back buttons.